# ios keyboard overlaps the input field focus in wkwebview

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, iphone, iphone-keypad

i just created a chat application, which has fixed header and footer.in footer i have div with position fixed,under input field. when i focus the textbox keypad popup and cover the input.it's not moving to top.
I am using the wkWebview and loading my website, which is a angular project.

Thanks in Advance